# Copying and pasting values from one dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes (df1, df2).

df1
[image]

df2

[image]

I would like to have the final dataframe like this:

Final dataframe

[image]

How do I do this using Pandas?

Comment: Do include your data as text, not images. You can take a look at `updates` function or `fillna`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** The following solution is suggested by @sophocles

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c'],
                    'val1':[1,None,3],
                    'val2':[4,5,6] })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['b'],
                    'val1':2})
```

`df1` and `df2`:

```
  name  val1  val2
0    a   1.0     4
1    b   NaN     5
2    c   3.0     6

  name  val1
0    b     2
```

Simply using `fillna`

```
df1.set_index('name').fillna(df2.set_index('name')).reset_index()
```

This one is much faster than using `merge` method

Comment: I think you can get to the answer in a simpler way, with using alignment on indices. Kind of like ```df1.set_index('name').fillna(df2.set_index('name')).reset_index()```

Comment: @sophocles: thank you so much, I don't know we could do that with `fillna`. Yours is much better